# Doubt on capacitors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, capacitance

Consider 4 capacitors connected in series 
Now a +2Q and +4Q charges are given simultaneously at marked locations in figure. Ignore the points A and B.
My doubt is about the charge distribution that will take place after the charges are added. How will that happen?
 [image]

I approached the problem during charge q appears on one plate and then accordingly giving charges plates. See picture below.
[image]

Here you will see that at the end plates the net charge should be zero(charge conservation) as initially there was no charge in that branch and charge was supplied to it. But in my charge distribution in the figure above this is not satisfied. Please tell me if I am going wrong anywhere.

Comment: Hi Dhruv and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: I know about that sir. But I am not asking you a homework question. This a genuine doubt. I want to know what really happens when charge is given to capacitors in such a way. Also I want to know how my approach is wrong because charge conservation is not occuring. I don't think by asking this question I am asking you to answer a homework problem. The question is a doubt about the working of capacitors in case described above.

Comment: Also your meta site mentions I should narrow down the problem with the concept with which I am having a doubt. I have done that. The actual question does not ask anything about charge distribution, this is a doubt that I have. Also I have mentioned my approach and not just asked a question. So I request you to help me with this doubt.

Comment: Total charge on the 2 plates connected to A will be zero, and same for the 2 plates connected to B. Other connected pairs of plates will have total charges +4Q and +2Q. Also, going round the circuit the algebraic sum of PDs across the capacitors will be zero (Kirchhoff's Voltage Law).

Comment: @sammygerbil   Yes you are right but if you see the second picture i posted there the charge on plate plates connected to A is not conserved. Could you please point out where my charge distribution is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your setup is too complicated. In order to understand the problem it is
better to simplify it to only 2 capacitors. Look at figure below.

[image]

We have two equal capacitors, initially uncharged. Consider that we have two disconnected conductors:

- one is formed by the upper plates of both capacitors an the connecting wire
- the other by plates and wire below.

Now we put a charge $Q$ on upper conductor, and ask which charges will
be found at equilibrium at the various points of circuit.

Note that we must distinguish between charge appearing on the internal
faces of plates and on the external ones. I'm afraid you made no
distinction and at the same time assumed that *total* charges on the opposite
plates of a capacitor are to be equal and opposite in sign. This is
true in usual situations, where a capacitor as a whole has zero net
charge. But this is not true in our setup.

So let's be cautious: let's call $+q$ the charge on the *inner* face of
upper plate (the same $q$ for both capacitors, by symmetry). Rest of
charge $Q$, i.e. $Q-2q$, will be found on upper face and on wire.
As to lower conductor, which is uncharged, we can safely assume that
the internal faces of lower plates carry charges $-q$ and the rest
(external faces + wire a total charge $+2q$.

And we are finished. I mean that in general nothing more can be said,
in absence of further information. Or at least of reasonable
hypotheses. As a guide consider the simplest case of a single
capacitor normally charged, i.e. with opposite charges on its plates.
Where exactly are those charges located? I assume you will answer - on
inner faces. And you would be right, at least for the usual building of capacitors. I mean that a usual capacitor is so made that almost no field lines escape: each one exiting from positive plate terminates on the negative
one. This can be attained in various ways. For a parallel plate
capacitor, like the ones in our figures, it is necessary that plates'
distance be much smaller than their diameters.

Under such hypothesis we have $q = Q/2$. You see that upper outer
faces and wire remain uncharged, whereas lower outer faces and wire
globally carry a charge $Q$.

---

Now we can come back to your problem. I'll not give the full solution,
but only a hint. Solve it by three steps:

- In first step, consider charge $4Q$ alone. You should be able to
  solve this sub-problem following my reasoning above.
- Second step: consider only charge $2Q$.
- Third step: use the principle of superposition.

Comment: Thanks for poniting out my conceptual mistake. i will try the question with method suggested by you. Thanks again.